# Where can I find Amethyst?

Tags: rune-factory-tod

I recently bought Rune Factory: Tides of Destiny and I'm hooked despite my gaming tastes.

Now I'm in need for a better weapon so: **Where can I find Amethyst, which is used to make Luck Blades(Dual Blades)?**

I'm at the Flame Shrine now (final floor tough).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amethysts are dropped by Monster Boxes, which are those toothy treasure-chest-looking guys that can be found on the Desert Island or the third floor of the Earth Spirit Shrine. They're also dropped by Mimics (blue Monster Boxes) and grown by Gigantuses (blue trolls), but I don't think you'll be able to get either of those until you get to the next shrine.

Comment: i see! thanks, tough i'm at the water shrine and came accros it by accident XD.